# Meteor.js: Submit event not firing

Tags: meteor

I've noticed after just starting to experiment with Meteor that if I have 2 forms on a page, it seems to only handle events for one. I have to seperate forms that need to be on the same page, one is nested within the other's template. Now the nested form will submit and the event will fire, but the composeMessageForm event will never fire. I've experienced this before with another project I was trying out.

Here's the main .js file: (**I'm also aware that there are probably bugs in the first event, I just never could get the event to fire so I could figure it out.**)

```
Template.inbox.events({
    "submit .composeMessageForm": function(event) {
      var to = event.target.to.value;
      var text = event.target.message.value;
      alert(to);
      if($.trim(text) != '' && $.trim(to) != '')
      {
        var foundUser = Users.findOne({username: to});
        if(foundUser)
        {
          if(!Conversations.find({from: username, to:foundUser.username}))
          {
            var c = Conversations.insert({
              from: username,
              to: foundUser.username,
              createdAt: new Date()
            });
            if(c)
            {
              Messages.insert({
                conversationId: c._id,
                from: username,
                text: text,
                sentAt: new Date()
              });
            }
          }
          else
          {
            console.log("Can't recreate conversations!");
          }
        }
        else
        {
          alert("No such user exists.");
        }
      }
      event.target.to.value   = "";
      event.target.text.value = "";
      return false;
    }
  });

  Template.inbox.helpers({
    conversations: function() {
      return Conversations.find({$or: [{from: username}, {to: username}]});
    }
  });

  Template.conversation.events({
    "submit .newMessageForm": function(event)
    {
      var conversationId = event.target.conversationId.value;
      var text = event.target.text.value;
      if($.trim(text) != '')
      {
        Messages.insert({
          conversationId: conversationId,
          text: text,
          from: username,
          sentAt: new Date()
        });
      }
      event.target.text.value = "";
      return false;
    }
  });
```

And here's the template:

```
<template name="inbox">
  <div class="composeMessage" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <form class="composeMessageForm">
      <input type="text" name="to" placeholder="Username" />
      <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message..." />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="inbox">
    {{#each conversations}}
      {{> conversation}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="conversation">
  <div class="conversation" id="conversationId-{{_id}}">
    {{#if equals currentUser.username from}}
      <strong>{{to}}</strong><br /><br />
    {{else}}
      <strong>{{from}}</strong><br /><br />
    {{/if}}
    <div class="messages">
      {{#each findMessagesForConversation ./_id}}
        <div>{{from}}: {{text}}
        <i>Sent {{formatDateSince sentAt}} ago.</i>
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
    <div class="newMessage">
      <form class="newMessageForm">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Message here..." />
        <input type="hidden" value="{{./_id}}" name="conversationId" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

## EDIT!:

So I appear to have hacked it into working by putting a submit button in the form, but then making it's visibility hidden so that you can't see it.

Comment: Yeah I don't think forms can fire a submit event without a submit button.

Comment: You can see the other form has no submit button and still works. Also none the Meteor tutorials or resources say anything about this.

Comment: It's not really a meteor thing - form submit events are a native browser event. I agree though that it would be nice to have a tutorial about this.